# How to align multiple labeled inline block input controls along the same vertical line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have 4 labeled drop-down controls succeeding one another along the inline document axis. How can I style them so that the control boxes themselves are aligned along the same vertical line?

As you can see, currently the varying height of each label causes the drop-downs to appear at a different point, vertically:

[image: Screenshot of current (undesired) layout]

Comment: Show your code and I will come with answer

Comment: Please show the rendered html rather than whatever that is

Comment: By "input boxes" you mean the labels? The selects in the picture are already all the same height.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the dropdown boxes. I want them to be align instead of the label

Comment: If the elements are not all in the same parent, this is not possible with CSS. You would need JS. There is **no** CSS method of equalising heights of elements that *do not share a parent*.

Comment: @Paulie_D I believe you are mistaken -- the Grid layout can lay the boxes out the way the person wants.

Comment: Nope....it can't. **Unless**, they share a parent which is my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be too difficult with a Grid layout:

```
<div>
    <label>Field 1....</label>
    <select></select>
    <label>Long Field Field Field Field Field</label>
    <select></select>
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <select></select>
    <label>Long Field Field Field Field Field</label>
    <select></select>
</div>
```

You make the container a Grid container:

```
div {
    display: grid;
}
```

And make sure the labels go on the first row only:

```
div > label {
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

Since your Grid container is a `div` it occupies all available space horizontally, and the label text may never wrap. Since you were concerned about input controls being aligned vertically, that will happen even if the labels have different height, you can test with limiting their width with, for instance:

```
div > label {
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

Don't forget to associate your `label` elements each with their respective control (using the `for` attribute for the `label`).